# How to pass variable to redirected page via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect, post

I'm using Ajax for my form POST, that way I can easily use validation on the page.

The  line below is the Python which I'm not using anymore:

```
return self.redirect("partner/snarf", src=src)
```

`src` is the data that I need to retrieve on the next page

My jQuery

```
$(form).unbind('submit').bind("submit", function(event) {
    WHOAT.networking.postViaAjax('/partner', params, function (response) {
        // if success!
        if (response.statusText === "OK") {

            // Here is the Ajax redirect, and need to also attach the src               
            WHOAT.networking.redirectToURL('/partner/snarf/');

        // if error
        } else if (response[0].message) {
            var errorMessage = response[0].message;
            $('#portal_container .warning p').text(errorMessage);
            $('#portal_container .warning').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Ajax functions

```
var postViaAjax = function (url, params, callback) {
    ajaxCall(url, params, callback, 'POST');
}

var ajaxCall = function(url, params, callback, postMethod) {
    $.ajax({
        type: postMethod,
        url: url,
        data: params,
        success: callback,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            },
            201: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            },
            400: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How would you send the src through?
One way I'm thinking is via the URL, it's the next step I'm going to try out...

Comment: yes use the url to pass the data as GET request

Comment: Add the URL to the params you're already sending to the server.

Comment: where you find the value of "src".
Inside the response of ajax call? in a into the current scope of Javascript? you need that **src** is an attributes of `redirectToURL` like: `WHOAT.networking.redirectToURL('/partner/snarf/',src)`? or add `src` to current params like: `WHOAT.networking.redirectToURL('/partner/snarf/'+src)` ??

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this `WHOAT.networking.redirectToURL('/partner/snarf/?src='+params.register_src);`

Comment: i think it will work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
redirectToURL('/partner/snarf/?src='+params.register_src);
```

Will add the src variable to the URL and pass it along that way

These will also work:

```
redirectToURL('/partner/snarf/',src)? or add src to current params like:    
redirectToURL('/partner/snarf/'+src)
```

thx to [@Frogmouth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2956107/frogmouth)